# WordPressのAJAXで別ドメインのphpからjsonデータ取得

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

WordPressからAJAXでドメインが異なるphpからデータを取得（JSON形式）したいと考えております。
ブラウザにhtt形式でhttps://〇〇〇.jp/test.php?des=50とうつと、JSONデータが表示されます。
このdes=50をGET形式ではなく、ブラウザからユーザーが入力した値をPOST形式で送りたいです。
function.phpに以下のコードを書いているのですが、successのあとにfalseというよくわからない内容が戻ってきます。

以下は、function.phpに記述している内容です。

```
function ajax_scripts() {
  $handle = 'tour_main';
  $file   = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $handle . '.js';
  wp_register_script( $handle, $file, array( 'jquery' ) );

  $action = 'tourajax-action';

  wp_localize_script( $handle, 'TOURAJAX_AJAX', [
      'api'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'action' => $action,
      'nonce'  => wp_create_nonce( $action )
  ]);
  wp_enqueue_script( $handle );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_scripts' );


function ajax_tourajax_call () {
  $action = 'tourajax-action';
  $data   = '';

  if( check_ajax_referer( $action, 'nonce', false ) ) {
        $data = @file_get_contents("https://〇〇〇.jp/test.php?des=50");
        if ( is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
            echo $data->get_error_message();
            exit;
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json( $data );
        }

  } else {
    status_header( '403' );
    $data = 'Forbidden';
  }
  header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
  echo wp_send_json( $data );

  //die();これは必要？？
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tourajax-action',        'ajax_tourajax_call' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tourajax-action', 'ajax_tourajax_call' );
```

以下は、jsに書いている内容です。

```
jQuery("#testbutton").click( function(){
        var JSONdata = {
            action: TOURAJAX_AJAX.action,
            nonce: TOURAJAX_AJAX.nonce,
            des: jQuery("#des").val()
        };

    alert(JSON.stringify(JSONdata));

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : TOURAJAX_AJAX.api,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSONdata,
        scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
        success : function(data) {

            // Success
            alert("success");
            alert(data);
            jQuery("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error : function(data) {

            // Error
            alert("error");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            jQuery("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
})
```

どなたか教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents`はエラー時にfalseをかえします。当然ながら`WP_Error`ではないので`is_wp_error`は無駄です。(また、ここでかえってきたfalseがレスポンスになっているとおもわれます。)

`file_get_contents`でHTTPリクエストを行うのは色々と不便な点もあります。WP内で外部にリクエストをするために[`wp_remote_request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/),[`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/)等が用意されているのでこれを使うことをおすすめします。引数については[`WP_Http::request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/)を参照ください。

Answer (score 0):

`wp_send_json();` は

> JSONとしてエンコード、プリントしてdie

らしいので、この時点でレスポンスボディが送出されてしまいます。
ですので、`header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );`はもっと早い段階で実行する必要がありますし、`echo wp_send_json( $data );`は不要です。

参考）https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/wp_send_json